# Show that if $b>0; \mathrm{cor}(x,z)=\mathrm{cor}(x,y)$.

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, covariance, correlation

Did I take a wrong turn somewhere?  I don't know where to go from here...  Can I not do the division in step 6?  Can standard deviation or cor(x,y) ever be zero?

4. Let x and y be jointly distributed numeric variables and let z=a+by, where a and b are constants.  Show that cov(x,z)=b*cov(x,y).  <-done already

**finished Proof**
 Thanks, Thomas!

[image]

Comment: There is some context missing here. What are $x,y,z,b$?

Comment: It is possible for $\mathrm{cov}(x,y)$ to be zero. It is also possible for $\mathrm{sd}(x)$ to be zero, but then $\mathrm{cor}(x,y)$ is undefined. (Standard deviation is zero when the vector is constant.)

Comment: Presumably, $x,y$ are vectors and $z=(a+by_i)_i$?

Comment: Why are there $x_i$ in your computation of $\mathrm{sd}(y)$ and $\mathrm{sd}(z)$?

Comment: Thomas Andrews, you are right, sorry.  I've added in the information.  The x_i are part of the definition of sd from my text.  sd is the square root of the variance, and the variance has the x_i in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step 6 is fine, because when any of the standard deviations is zero, correlation is undefined.

So you need to prove that $b\cdot\mathrm{sd}(y)=\mathrm{sd}(a+by)$.

Your next line is odd, because you have $x_i$ on both sides, but:

$$\mathrm{sd}(y)=\sqrt{\sum (y_i-\mu(y))^2}\\
\mathrm{sd}(a+by)=\sqrt{\sum (a+by_i - \mu(a+by))^2}$$

Then use that $\mu(a+by)=a+b\mu(y)$.

And since your proof is actually the reverse, you don't need to be worried about multiplying both sides by $\mathrm{cov}(x,y)$. That is, the "real" proof is to start by proving that $\mathrm{sd}(a+by)=b\cdot\mathrm{sd}(y)$, then reversing your argument above. So the only thing you need is that $\mathrm{sd(x)}$ and $\mathrm{sd(y)}$ are non-zero.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot.  I was typing the formula from what was in the book and forgot to change the x's to y's.  (I got the mu one right, but not the other)  Oops.  I'll make the change and see if I can see where to go from there.

Comment: finished, your comments helped me a lot.

Comment: Just remember that the proof is actually your argument in reverse - you need to deduce the result from a true equality, not deduce a true equality from the result. @DanaHill

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure I understand the difference.  I never took an "intro to proof" class, just trying to figure this out as I go  (new grad student in Math without an undergrad math degree).  So far, every time I've had this type of proof, I've done it like I did here.  It's been accepted every time.  So far.